# Help with reversing decryption in assembly

Tags: decryption

I've used x64dbg to work out decryption in a particular program. I've found where it changes the encrypted material into readable text but can't work out the best way to use this information to convert multiple files.

Is it a standardized encryption method? (eg. blowfish/aes) 
[image: Assembler]

It basically copies the file to memory then cycles through this (and one other cycle above it).

Thanks!

Addit 15/12/2019:
**OUTER FUNCTION**
[image]

Ouput of signsrch:

```
  offset   num  description [bits.endian.size]
  --------------------------------------------
  0002b542 2249 TEA1_DS [32.le.4]
  00059090 2065 Haval init [32.le.32&]
  00059090 919  Blowfish bfp table [32.le.72]
  000590b0 1054 Haval hash pass2 [32.le.128&]
  000590e0 921  Blowfish ks0 table [32.le.1024]
  000590e0 2335 Blowfish_s_init [32.le.4096]
  00059138 2067 Haval mc3 [32.le.128]
  00059198 2219 HAVAL2_DS [32.le.32]
  000591b8 2069 Haval mc4 [32.le.128]
  00059218 2217 HAVAL1_DS [32.le.32]
  00059238 2071 Haval mc5 [32.le.128]
  000594e0 923  Blowfish ks1 table [32.le.1024]
  000598e0 925  Blowfish ks2 table [32.le.1024]
  00059ce0 927  Blowfish ks3 table [32.le.1024]
  007b1a86 2545 anti-debug: IsDebuggerPresent [..17]
  007b7e07 1038 padding used in hashing algorithms (0x80 0 ... 0) [..64]
```

It must be blowfish. Now to find the key!!!

Comment: See if this helps: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18673/how-to-identify-known-encryption-algorithm

Comment: Can you post the cycle above? Also, checking the memory reads at the constants `48 448 848 C48` would be very valuable. Lookup tables usually make spotting the respective crypto algorithm easy. I have a feeling this is AES or AES-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably Blowfish.

Googling the constants "0x448 0xC48 crypto" lead to this post:

[Trying to identify block of code which generates 256 bit key](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/trying-to-identify-block-of-code-which-generates-256-bit-key)

where someone in the comments wrote

```
googling the constants 0xc48, 0x848 and 0x448 is a good idea.
rohitab.com/discuss/topic/36066-blowfish relates this to blowfish somehow
```

and that link has code that looks very similar:

http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/36066-blowfish/

(search for `C48` there).

The only oddity is that the author of that other post says he is sure it is AES and he said he could decrypt some data using AES. I don't know how to consolidate both ideas, but it's probably either and given the similar disassemblies I'd say Blowfish.

Doesn't look like AES to me either but I had some AES-related crypto before that looked a bit like this - Blowfish is way more convincing.

Comment: That is really helpful!! See above edited post. It must be blowfish. Now I just have to work out where the key and IV is in assembly :-) At least I know what I'm looking for now.